# Rust code of lifetime constrains not work?

Tags: rust, lifetime

```rust
fn do_sth<'a, 'b, 'c>(arg1: &'a i32, arg2: &'b i32) -> &'c i32
where
    'a: 'b,
    'b: 'c,
{
    arg2
}


fn do_sth2<'a, 'b>(arg1: &'a i32, arg2: &'b i32) -> i32
where
    'a: 'b    
{
    10
}


fn main() {
    let mario = 1;
    let ref1 = &mario;
    {
        let luigi = 2;
        let ref2 = &luigi;
        {
            let peach = do_sth(&ref2, &ref1);
            let test = do_sth2(&ref2, &ref1);
        }
    }
}
```

For function do_sth, lifetime parameter 'a should longer than lifetime parameter 'b( where 'a: 'b,), my question is why the compiler allow statement below

```rust
let peach = do_sth(&ref2, &ref1)
```

to compile ?

Comment: I think it's that you're using `&ref1` and `&ref2`, which are both `&&i32` of the same lifetime. What happens if you pass just `ref1` and `ref2` to the `do_sth[2]` functions?

Comment: `'a: 'b` doesn't mean `'a` must be longer than `'b`, it means `'b` can't be shorter than `'a`. The compiler can also choose a shorter lifetime than the _actual_ lifetime of the reference given to make the lifetimes fit. So here, the compiler can just choose to use the lifetime of `ref2` for both references.